# Can’t find oil filter for 2019 Jetta

Tags: jetta

Doing the first oil change for a 2019 Jetta I just bought. Put the car on stands and now I can’t find the filter anywhere. I can’t find any videos of this car on youtube yet. Any one do an oil change on this car yet?

Comment: Did you look under the hood on top of the engine?

Comment: Brand new car, but not a brand new engine.  Look for oil change how-to's on earlier models.  For instance, here is one of a [2017 oil change](https://youtu.be/1-Hz_QA8CQw) (I only watched long enough to see the filter was on the bottom, could be a terrible video...).

Answer (score 2):

Remove the under-engine cover. The oil filer is underneath the engine, facing forward towards the bottom edge of the electric radiator fan.

The video cited in comments above is for a 2017 Jetta, which has different bodywork. Here's a video (not mine) of oil + filter change on a 2019 Jetta: [youtube.com/watch?v=c2-A0N2ki78](http://youtube.com/watch?v=c2-A0N2ki78) You'll see the oil filter beginning at 4:57 into the video.